# Proguard doesnt preserve the line numbers and method names in stacktrace

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

Here are few lines from proguard-rules.pro

```
 -keepattributes *Annotation*
 -keepattributes Signature
 -keepattributes InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod
 -renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
 -keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
 -keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception
 -dontwarn org.apache.http.**
```

Logcat output (error line number is listed as 1133, while my source file is 100 lines longer)

```
09-04 16:11:46.698 3827-5280/com.XX.main E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[ActivityRecognizedTracker]
Process: com.XX.main, PID: 3827
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'double com.XX.trips.Trip.a' on a null object reference
at com.XX.ActivityRecognizedTracker.onHandleIntent(SourceFile:1133)
```

I am preserving the line numbers and source file attributes, but stack trace is still obfuscated. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

AFAIK it's not possible to obfuscate the code and have original stacktraces. So if you want to see original method and class names in the stacktrace, you have to add `-dontobfuscate` rule.

**But you don't really need the original stacktrace.**

You are using `-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable` and that enables you to [unambiguously retrace the stacktrace](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/tools/retrace#with). Just don't forget to keep the generated `mapping.txt` file.

Moreover if you remove `-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile` you'll see the original file names in the parentheses. The line number is already there, so you should be able to figure out without retracing where the exception actually happened.

Comment: Thanks! You helped me with exactly what I needed.