# Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber() obfuscated by proguard

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-proguard

Before Proguard with:

```
Throwable().getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber();
```

I got:

> 482

After Proguard I got:

> 41

Which is obviously wrong.

Here is the tested rules to solve this problem :

```
-keep class java.lang.StackElement
-keepattributes StackTraceElement
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes getStackTrace
```

But it doesn't work. Is there any specific rules to let this piece of code work properly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/examples#stacktrace), you need to do this:

```
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile    
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

and you need to use `-printmapping` to save the mappings so that you can then decode the obfuscated stacktraces.

I should point out that references to classes and methods in the standard class library will always be retained since they are needed when your code is loaded.  Therefore this "-keep" is superfluous:

```
-keep class java.lang.StackElement
```

And you are also telling Proguard to keep attributes called "StackTraceElement" and "getStackTrace" which don't exist.  The list of supported attributes is documented [here](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/usage/attributes)

See also:

- [Proguard doesnt preserve the line numbers and method names in stacktrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39322359/proguard-doesnt-preserve-the-line-numbers-and-method-names-in-stacktrace).  The question is different (you don't want to preserve method names!) but the accepted answer mentions the solution above.

Comment: Thank you for your precise and responsive answer.